# How to set cookie domain for staging and production site correctly?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a staging site https://dev.example.com and a production site https://example.com

I don‘t want to share any cookies between those sites obviously and I want to be sure that I don‘t break anything login related.

I‘m a confused how to set the cookie domain under settings-web correctly. I read that you have to put a dot in front of the domain so it would be .dev.example.com and .example.com

Just to be sure, is this correct? Thx

Edit: And what about the option „use http only“. Do I have to set it to no?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the domain for a cookie from `System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management` in this section you need to set Cookie Domain to your domain and Cookie Path value as `/`. After saving the value you need to flush the cache storage as well as clear the cookie from the browser

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know but my question is how to set it correctly. Is it with a dot or without? And what about the „http only“ setting

Comment: Just set the cookie domain. Leave everything else default.

Comment: no, you need to add your domain without `dot` like `example.com` and without `http` @zlep